# Opera + XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, opera

I`m from Russia, so sorry for my bad English.

I want to load the main page of my site by js, and i use this script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
 alert(httpGet('http://site.ru'));
</script>
```

Script located at site.ru/page123.

It works in Firefox and really alert my main page, but if i run it in Opera, nothing happens. Please, fix my code, i can`t see any error in it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR is usually asynchronous (switching it to synchronous mode is not recommended for reasons like **freezing the browser**). You better use a callback.

Since dealing with XHR manually is annoying, I'd suggest you to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). Using jQuery your code would look like this (that's just the easiest/most simple way to do it):

```
$.get('http://site.ru', function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but main page size is smaller, then jQuery framework. I don`t want to load script, more than my site ;)

Comment: Minified jQuery is just 29kb. Even with a slow connection that's loaded in almost no time.

Comment: It is unnecessary to load a jQuery library just for purposes of sending an XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: It is a real pain in the ass to make an XMLHttpRequest work in all browsers without jQuery